# Why does implementing threading in Python cause I/O to become really slow?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have this function that saves a large list of dictionaries into files of 100 items each. This worked flawlessly in a normal environment, but after changing nothing but running this using threading, I experienced rather significant slow-downs. To my knowledge, simply adding threading or multiprocessing shouldn't cause slowdowns in I/O, but if I am missing something trivial, please let me know, but if I am not, how can I make this not run so slowly?

```py
def savePlayerQueueToDisk(saveCopy):
        print("="*10)
        print("Application exit signal received. Caching loaded players...")
        import pickle
        i = 0
        for l in chunks(saveCopy, 100):
            with open(CACHED_PLAYERS_DIR / f"{str(i)}", 'wb') as filehandle:
                pickle.dump(saveCopy, filehandle)
            i += 1
            print(f"saved chunk {i}")
        import sys
        print("="*10)
        sys.exit()
```

```py
def mainFunction():
    # Calls a main program, where on KeyboardException, it calls the savePlayerQueueToDisk function.
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=main, kwargs={'ignore_exceptions': False})
    t2.start()
```

Edit: After some more testing, by using multiprocessing instead of threading, and *only* using a second process for the one of the threads, and keeping the mainFunction on the main thread, I experienced no slowdowns. Why is this the case?

Edit: after more testing and debugging, I found that the issue is not actually tied to multiprocessing and I/O bounding. In fact, there is actually a logic error on line 8 of my `savePlayerQueueToDisk()` function. It reads `pickle.dump(saveCopy, filehandle)`, when it should instead be `pickle.dump(l, filehandle)`. The I/O would just get slower and slower the more I ran the function because I would save the entire list into over 100 files, and when all those files were loaded in, I would save 100 copies of each data again into over 100 files. Loading and saving these, obviously, would just get out of hand.

Comment: It depends.  If you followed your `mainFunction` with `while True:` / `pass`, then it's going to slow down because your main thread is tying up 100% of a CPU.  If your main thread doesn't relinquish the CPU, the child threads can't run.

Comment: I don't use a while True: pass in this thread. I have a separate thread that has a `while True:` / `doSomething` / `time.sleep(60)` is that slowing down this thread?

Comment: Since your process is I/O-constained, you may have better luck using async than threading.

Comment: If you're sleeping, that's fine.  But remember that any CPU-bound thread will prevent other Python threads from running.  Only one Python thread can run at a time.

Comment: Whatever storage device you're working from probably can't do many things at once very efficiently. This is especially true for spinning rust.

Answer (score 0):

After more testing and debugging, I found that the issue is not actually tied to multiprocessing and I/O bounding. In fact, there is actually a logic error on line 8 of my s`avePlayerQueueToDisk()` function. It reads `pickle.dump(saveCopy, filehandle)`, when it should instead be `pickle.dump(l, filehandle)`. The I/O would just get slower and slower the more I ran the function because I would save the entire list into over 100 files, and when all those files were loaded in, I would save 100 copies of each data again into over 100 files. Loading and saving these, obviously, would just get out of hand.